# How do you plot a data frame series that you've used groupby on in pandas / matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a data frame series called 'attend' where I was asked to return the count of each of each of the occurrences on. The series values were either 'yes' or 'no' or 'maybe'.

I created the group using: `group1 = df.groupby('attend')`

How do I graph this? When I try to use `df['attend].plot.bar()` in pandas, nothing happens, unlike when I made my histogram.

I do know how to do this using value_counts() but can someone show me how to do this another way?

Answer (score 0):

I will take a stab at your question. Please let me know if this is not what you are looking for.

```
### create data
np.random.seed(47)

df = pd.DataFrame({'attend' : np.random.choice(['yes', 'no', 'some'], 100),
                  'other_random_col' : np.random.choice(['a', 'b', 'c'], 100),
                  'int_col' : np.random.sample(100)})
```

Now, there are different ways to go about this but pandas will return a [groupby object](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

Depending on what you want -- `value_counts()` is probably a preferred method for a single series. However, you could do something like this to retain the counts for the single column under a groupby:

```
df.groupby('attend')['attend'].value_counts().plot.bar()
```

Now, to get the value counts of a single series this seems like more work than just doing `df.attend.value_counts().plot.bar()` but it would work for you.